# Intellij IDEA - remove/reformat double spaces in html template (class tag)

Tags: intellij-idea

anyone know how to configure Intellij to remove double/triple spaces between class names?
I cannot find such setting in Editor HTML configuration.
If its help. It is not really html it is "Vue Template"
For example, i have such code, Extra spaces after format should be removed. "Editor settings => HTML => in "keepWhitespaces" InputField are only pre and textarea tags

```
<div class="d-flex   flex-column align-items-center   mb-2   " v-if="errorMessage">
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is not supported yet. Feel free to vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43730 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-47818.

Comment: @Oksana Understood. Thanks for the answer.
I would vote with pleasure, but as far as I can see. Unregistered users are not allowed to vote. What I think in this case is not very open to users.
Not every user has a jetbrains account and in order to vote, register - somehow I think it's too much.